# Помогите с объектами в javascript

Tags: javascript

Помогите решить проблему. Функция `a()` должна создать новый объект такой же структуры как аргумент и в этом новом объекте приплюсовать 2.

```
function a(arg){
    arg.value += 1;
    return arg; 
}

var c = 
    {
        name: 'Название 1',
        value: 2
    };

var b = a(c);

console.log(c);
```

Answer (score 1):

Если не заходить глубоко внутрь объектов, т.е. выполнять поверхностное копирование вместо глубокого, то можно сделать так:

```
function a(arg) {
    var result = {};
    for (var key in arg)
        result[key] = arg[key];
    result.value += 2;
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Сделал так:

```
function a(arg) {
    var clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arg));
    clone.value += 1;
    return clone;
}
var c = {
    name: 'Название 1',
    value: 2
};
var b = a(c);

console.log(c.value); // 2
console.log(b.value); // 3
```

Comment: Ужасно неэффективное решение.

Answer (score 1):

Создать клон объекта можно так (источник: https://stackoverflow.com/a/122190):

```
function clone(obj) {
  if (obj === null || typeof(obj) !== 'object' || 'isActiveClone' in obj)
    return obj;

  if (obj instanceof Date)
    var temp = new obj.constructor(); //or new Date(obj);
  else
    var temp = obj.constructor();

  for (var key in obj) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) {
      obj['isActiveClone'] = null;
      temp[key] = clone(obj[key]);
      delete obj['isActiveClone'];
    }
  }

  return temp;
}
```

В некоторых браузерах для клонирования объектов можно использовать новую функция [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).